# Apache Click - layered directory issue

Tags: apache, click, velocity, click-framework

So, im developing my own webpage and im having an issue with getting the velocity template engine to find my .htm inside a directory under WebContent/.

Im pretty sure my web.xml is correct and my click.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<click-app>
    <pages package="com.clickapp.pages" automapping="true">
    </pages>
<click-app>
```

I had tried before to manually map these troublesome .htm to their respective classnames but I kept getting page not found or an exception page telling me it was not able to find the resource "/directory/page.htm"

I believe I am following correct templating schemes wih my java packages for the directory above being "com.clickapp.pages.directory.pagePage".

Note: I am running on latest version of click and my server is Apache Tomcat 7.0

If any more information is needed, please ask and I will provide.

Comment: With further debugging I was able to get the htm page to render accidentally by setting in the click.xml mode value to debug. I have no idea why that worked, but the issue still stands that the css and jquery arw not loading. In firebug, the css cannot be found, even though it is looking in the exact address it should be found

Comment: Openning the css document in the browser gives a 404 page not found (resource not found) even though the file exists there. Im beginning to feel like folders off of WebContent are not recognized by click? But how do i change that...?

Comment: Just realized I am receiving a TOMCAT 404 resource not found, not an error by Click. Must be an issue with Tomcat permissions within the WebContent folder. My css and js are crudely hard coded in all of my pages so it must be calling a get to receive them seperately from the htm which is denied by tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

After recent considerations I decided to try the issue on a seperate workspace, in a seperate server. The results of this test contradicted what was happening on my main workspace so I decided a reset should go into effect. I simply trashed the server and made a new one, fixing my issue.

tl;dr - Made new server to run on. Solved issue.

My guess is in fiddling with the server when I didnt know what I was doing at the beginning of the project somehow screwed up a configuration causing my issue.